# Easy way to bind dynamic elements without having to recall functions jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a page in which users can drag content around, resize it, etc.

The basic structure looks like the following:

```
$('.element').on().resizable().draggable();
```

When called at the beginning of the document load it adds bind events, resizable and draggable. Now the problem I have is that a user can add in new elements dynamically. These new elements are no longer covered by the above code. What I ended up doing is the following:

```
function bindEvents(){
    $('.element').on().resizable().draggable();
}
```

bindEvents();

And then when elements are added I turn off the current implementation and then turn it on again so that it will include the new elements:

```
$('.element').off().resizable("destroy").draggable("destroy");
bindEvents();
```

No I know this is incredibly inefficient and most likely uses way more memory than needed. My question is, is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to add the one particular element to the already established group of bound elements?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get a chance to implement my solution? 2 methods and you eliminate all the destroying and remaking by only binding to things which haven't already been bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to waste work on the old items then brand them with something and avoid them later, or vice versa.

```
function bindEvents(){
    $('.element').not('.initialized').addClass('initialized')
        .on().resizable().draggable();
}
```

Comment: the memory consumption of the original script was around 79.25 average. With the modifications it hovers around 78.15MB. So a small decrease, but not quite as much as I was hoping for. I guess another question would then be, can it be decreased dramatically?

Comment: Where are you getting "memory consumption" from? No, this is almost as efficient as possible without tossing out jQuery and doing it all by hand. What makes destroying and rebuilding everything the wrong solution is that it's a lot of work for the browser to do with each new element load, and the situation gets progressively worse as the page grows. This solution makes sure that there is no destruction, just one instantiation per element.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use the delegation functionality of [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and bind to a container of the elements?

```
$('#container').on('mouseover', '.element', function(e) {
    $(this).resizable().draggable();
});
```

You'd want to add the styling for the draggable classes to be there by default, but this is easily accomplished by adding the `ui-resizable` class to the elements:

```
<div class="element ui-resizable">Foo</div>
```

Any elements that match the filter (`'.element'`) will automatically get the functionality when they are added to `#container`

Comment: why mouseover? wont that cause the binding to occur more often than necessary?

Comment: The `.on()` portions of his code could certainly be extracted from this predicament by delegating them to a permanant "container", but `.resizable()` and `.draggable()` are doing much more than binding event handlers so there is no `.delegate()` equivalent.

Comment: @Sinetheta Seems to work: http://sandbox.pangram.net/delegate/ Add another `<div class="element">` via the console and it's resizable and draggable.

Comment: @steveax I think you may be missing the point of `.resizable()` and `.draggable()`, this is akin to building a new engine for your car every time you turn the key in the ignition.